# iOS init configurations

Tags: ios, methods, configuration, init

I have a custom class which subclasses `UIView`. I have some configurations which I would like to do but from what I read, the use of messages towards `self` is discouraged in the `init` method. This is my `init` method:

```
- (id) initWithMondayFirst:(BOOL)mondayFirst timeZone:(NSTimeZone*)timeZone andMonth:(NSDate*) month
{
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, VIEW_WIDTH, VIEW_HEIGHT)]){
        _timeZone = timeZone;
        _mondayFirst = mondayFirst;
        _currentMonth = [month monthBeginning];
        [self configureNumberOfRows];
        [self configureLimitations];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
        [self configureDimensions];
        [self configureMonthLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

My question is, where should I put all those configuration methods? I need them by the time I reach the `drawRect:` method. I thought of putting them in it but I don't think it's a good idea. Thanks.

PS: most of those config methods configure some of the properties of the class.

Comment: Everything looks good in your code. Just mark it as `designated`

Comment: @Tala, are you referring to ``#pragma mark``?

Comment: No, it is just a comment that you leave for yourself and other developers. There is no way to restrict using `init` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put those configuration methods into the designated initializer method. More information about the designated initializers can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3)